# Poor UnionAggregate (CLR aggregate) performance - CPU cost hint?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, spatial, sql-clr

I'm trying to use SQL Server Spatial to work with data related to geographic regions defined by a third party, and am having trouble getting acceptable performance.

The following query takes quite a long time to run, and doesn't use any parallel operators:

```
UPDATE
    tblRegions
SET
    RG_Geography = RegGeo
FROM
    tblRegions
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            geography::UnionAggregate(RGD_Geography) AS RegGeo
        FROM
            tblRegionDetail 
        WHERE
            RGD_RG_ID = RG_ID
    ) agg
```

If I convert that update to a select, it takes around 25 seconds to get a single region, and pegs one CPU core while doing so.  If I take out the aggregate, the select finishes almost instantly.  That makes it pretty clear that the aggregate itself is the problem.

Is there anything I can do to hint to the optimizer that the aggregate will have a high CPU cost?  In addition to that, is there anything I can do to get this update to run faster?  Adding parallel query hints has helped some, but hasn't gotten performance to anywhere near acceptable.

Comment: Can you please share Execution Plan?

Comment: You can share the plan here: https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: The plan, with parallel hints, is here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1JIpJuW7 .  The long-running aggregate is the "Stream Aggregate", which has a 0% estimated cost.

Comment: I also ran the update against a single row, and got an actual query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry0celuZQ

Comment: That's a pretty basic query. I don't think there is anything you can do. Perhaps you can migrate to PostGIS?